# Save GNSS accuracy for each vertex of polygon/line feature in QField

Tags: gps, qfield, accuracy, m-values

In QField it is possible to save positioning information in point features through expression variables like *@position_horizontal_accuracy* or *@position_number_of_used_satellites*. The explanation is given in the official QField documentation (https://qfield.org/docs/en/prepare/attributes-form.html).

For a comprehensive data accuracy assessment I want to save the abovementioned variables and maybe additional variables (e.g. *@position_vertical_accuracy*) for each vertex of line and polygon features. In 2017 Matthias Kuhn mentioned the possibility to theoretically do so by saving the information to the m-value of vertices but that it was not yet implemented (https://github.com/opengisch/QField/issues/179).

Is it possible to somehow store multiple GNSS position information for each vertex of a line/polygon feature? How?

If not, is it at least possible to only store horizontal accuracy as a single value in the m-value of vertices?

If not directly possible, are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, this is not possible just like that.

You could take a list of points and connect them to lines in a post processing step. And already visualize them as lines on QField using a virtual layer.

It would be possible to extend QField to store a (limited amount of) data in the m value per vertex. Or edit two layers in parallel. These are more ideas than ready to implement concepts though.