# Record time for each vertex of line in QField

Tags: qgis, line, time, vertices, qfield

I use QField 1.9.5, and QGIS 3.16, and I use GeoPackages to record vector data in QField. I use a line layer to record my track. I also use QField to record photographs taken with my tablet as points. I would like to record the time for each vertex of my track, so this can be extracted and used to geotag high-resolution photographs taken on a DSLR, where I have synchronized the camera's time with my tablet. Is it possible to record the time for each vertex in a line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although QField documentation states (https://qfield.org/docs/fieldwork/track_lines_polygons.html): "If the layer geometry supports m value, the time is stored in the m value, that passed since the first vertex of this tracking session has been recorded.", few weeks ago one of core QFIeld developers stated ([Save GNSS accuracy for each vertex of polygon/line feature in QField](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/392480/save-gnss-accuracy-for-each-vertex-of-polygon-line-feature-in-qfield/394534#394534)), that it is not possible to store any m-value through QField.
So it is not possible at the time. (I have tried this on a simple qfield project and it really does not work.)